# Unable to convert date with UTC using Joda Time API

Tags: java-8, jodatime, reactive-mongo-java

I'm trying to convert this date into local date

```
Input: "2021-04-20T15:00:00+02:00";

Expected output: "2021-04-20T13:00:00Z";

Actual output : "2021-04-20T15:00:00
```

Can you please let me know which library to use?

Code:

```
String date = "2021-04-20T15:00:00+02:00";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);

System.out.println(dt.toString());
```

Comment: While the official Joda-Time recommendation is to switch to java.time as the answers say, using Joda-Time `DateTime.parse(date).withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault())` yields `2021-04-20T16:00:00.000+03:00` when running in Asia/Qatar time zone. Is that your local time? What made you expect `2021-04-20T13:00:00Z`?

Comment: *which library*: Do you mean which library class from the Joda-Time library (`DateTime`, `LocalDateTIme`, `Instant`) or which library instead of Joda-Time (java.time/JSR-310, Time4J)? The latter question would be off-topic for Stack Overflow; the former is on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java-8` [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) to parse the input string (since it is in `ISO-8601`) and then use [toInstant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toInstant--)

```
String timeStamp = "2021-04-20T15:00:00+02:00";
OffsetDateTime.parse(timeStamp).toInstant() //2021-04-20T13:00:00Z
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

You used the wrong type, `LocalDateTime`. Use `OffsetDateTime` and `Instant`.

```
OffsetDateTime
.parse( "2021-04-20T15:00:00+02:00" )
.toInstant()
.toString()
```

## Details

The Joda-Time library is now In maintenance mode after having been succeeded years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310 and built into Java 8 and later.

Your input has an indicator of an offset-from-UTC of `+02:00`, two hours ahead of UTC. So parse as a `java.time.OffsetDateTime` object.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2021-04-20T15:00:00+02:00" ) ;
```

Adjust to UTC by merely extracting an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
```

Generate your desired output.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```